# How to turn on the Auto-Complete in Python Wing IDE?

Tags: python, autocomplete, ide, wing-ide

I am using the Python IDE Wing and just cannot seem to find the auto-complete option. Is there even such option in this program?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using Wing 101, which is a very scaled back version that does not have auto-completion.  It was designed for teaching beginning programmers and the professors we worked with in creating it felt auto-completion should be left off.

Wing IDE Personal and Wing IDE Pro both have auto-completion and much more; Wing 101 really is severely scaled back to make it simple for beginners.

Comment: I had a feeling that this was the reason. Other than that it's a great IDE

Comment: I agree, I mean why even have an ide if there no autocomplete, you can use notepad.!

Comment: For Wing 101 it was a design decision driven by educators wanting no completion for people just learning programming for the first time.  Personally I'd want it even then ;-) but that's why it's like that.